# How to simulate App Tombstoning with Android emulators? (for Xamarin.Android and MVVMCross)

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm using Xamarin.Android combined with MVVMCross and I'm researching its ViewModels lifecycles.

I can't get ReloadState within MvxViewModel to hit?
(but SaveState in MvxViewModel do get hit when I power down the emulator)

How to you simulate app Tombstoning with Android apps in the (Xamarin) emulator?
or is it a bug within MVVMCross?

PS: I used SaveStateToBundle with ReloadFromBundle
and SavedState SaveState() with ReloadState(SavedState savedState)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to simulate app tombstoning is to use the debug setting for "[Don't keep activities"

[image: Don't keep activities]

With this option chosen, then pressing Android home button causes the activities to be finished.

(Note that finishing the activities is not quite the same as flushing the app from memory though...)

Comment: OK, when I press the home button the SaveState and SaveStateToBundle won't hit the debugger. When I powerdown the emulator they do, but then the App will not reload because its still running.
Did I forget to implement something?

Comment: thanks for the info but I still can’t simulate a whole tombstone and recovery with an emulator. I set the Dev options as shown but never gets the ReloadState hit (while I have a SaveState). Has anyone ever succeeded to hit the ReloadState and what where the actions to reproduce this tombstoning?

Comment: The SaveState(Bundle) and ReloadState(Bundle) seem to work out of the box now.

Comment: If your app has any global state that is not specific to any activity, "Don't keep activities" will not discard it. In a true tombstoning scenario this data is discarded too. I haven't yet figured out a way to fully reproduce that.